# Issues with animation in CSS/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a typing effect using CSS/JavaScript, but I'm not succeeding. When I attempt to make the vertical bar move along with the content that's appearing on the screen, it just remains static and doesn't follow the text. The vertical bar is visible on the screen and its blinking effect is working, but it's not tracking the text. Would anyone know how to assist me with this?

EXAMPLE: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CcY_jtpbVvU&ab_channel=JetersonLordano

```
HTML:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo/styles.css">
  <title>Animação de digitação</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="message-container">
      <p id="message"></p>
      <div class="message-bar"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
      <img id="image" src="imagens/imagem1.jpeg" alt="Imagem">
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="02 script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
CSS:

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  background-color: #000000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image-container {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  padding-right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
}

#image {
  width: 65%; 
  max-width: 432px;
  height: auto;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.message-container {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding-left: 50px;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
}

#message {
  color: white;
  font-size: 28px;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  max-width: calc(100% - 50px);
}

.blink-caret {
  animation: blink-caret 0.75s infinite;
}

#image {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 1;
}


.message-bar {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 4px;
  height: 28px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 0.7;
  animation: blink-caret 0.75s infinite; 
}


@keyframes blink-caret {
  from,
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```
JavaScript:

const messages = [
  "My text here",
  "My text here",
  "My text here"
];

const images = [
  "imagens/imagem1.jpeg",
  "imagens/imagem2.jpeg",
  "imagens/imagem3.jpeg"
];

const messageElement = document.getElementById("message");
const imageElement = document.getElementById("image");
const messageBarElement = document.createElement("div");
messageBarElement.classList.add("message-bar");
messageElement.appendChild(messageBarElement);

let currentMessageIndex = 0;

function typeMessage(message) {
  let i = 0;
  messageElement.classList.remove("blink-caret");
  const typingInterval = setInterval(() => {
    if (i < message.length) {
      messageElement.textContent += message.charAt(i);
      i++;

      const lastCharPosition = messageElement.getBoundingClientRect().left + (i * 12);
      messageBarElement.style.left = `${lastCharPosition}px`;
    } else {
      clearInterval(typingInterval);
      messageBarElement.classList.add("blink-caret");
      setTimeout(eraseMessage, 2500);
    }
  }, 50);
}


function eraseMessage() {
  let i = messageElement.textContent.length - 1;
  const erasingInterval = setInterval(() => {
    if (i >= 0) {
      messageElement.textContent = messageElement.textContent.slice(0, i);
      i--;
    } else {
      clearInterval(erasingInterval);
      messageBarElement.classList.remove("blink-caret"); 
      imageElement.style.transition = "opacity 0.5s ease-in-out";
      imageElement.style.opacity = 0;

      setTimeout(() => {
        currentMessageIndex = (currentMessageIndex + 1) % messages.length;
        imageElement.src = images[currentMessageIndex];

        imageElement.style.transition = "opacity 0.5s ease-in-out";
        imageElement.style.opacity = 1;

        setTimeout(() => {
          messageElement.textContent = "";
          typeMessage(messages[currentMessageIndex]);
        }, 500);
      }, 500);
    }
  }, 30);
}

imageElement.src = images[currentMessageIndex];

typeMessage(messages[currentMessageIndex]);
```

Initial Attempt: The vertical bar was initially positioned at the end of the div, not moving along with the text as it was being typed. Attempts were made to adjust the CSS, but the issue remained unresolved.

HTML: Positioning: It was suggested to change the positioning of .message-bar in the HTML by placing it before the message paragraph. However, this did not solve the problem.

JavaScript - Position Calculation: An attempt was made to use JavaScript to calculate the current character's position in the text relative to the width of the message div. However, the vertical bar still did not properly follow the text.

CSS: Positioning with position: relative; and position: absolute;: It was suggested to add position: relative; to .message-container and position: absolute; to .message-bar, along with bottom: 0; and right: 0; to align the vertical bar in the bottom-right corner. Even with this approach, the bar was still not behaving as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this by putting the message into a real `input` element. You can style the `input` so that a user sees no difference from text in a `p` or a `div`. Once you give `focus` to that `input`, the **caret** (vertical bar) will follow the last character automatically.

```js
const messages = [
  "First text here",
  "Second text here",
  "Third text here"
];

const images = [
  "https://picsum.photos/id/51/500",
  "https://picsum.photos/id/52/500",
  "https://picsum.photos/id/53/500"
];

const messageElement = document.getElementById("message");
const messageInput = messageElement.querySelector("input");
const imageElement = document.getElementById("image");

let currentMessageIndex = 0;

function typeMessage(message) {
  messageInput.focus();
  let i = 0;
  messageElement.classList.remove("blink-caret");
  const typingInterval = setInterval(() => {
    if (i < message.length) {
      messageInput.value += message.charAt(i);
      i++;
    } else {
      clearInterval(typingInterval);
      setTimeout(eraseMessage, 2500);
    }
  }, 50);
}


function eraseMessage() {
  messageInput.focus();
  let i = messageInput.value.length - 1;
  const erasingInterval = setInterval(() => {
    if (i >= 0) {
      messageInput.value = messageInput.value.slice(0, i);
      i--;
    } else {
      clearInterval(erasingInterval);
      imageElement.style.transition = "opacity 0.5s ease-in-out";
      imageElement.style.opacity = 0;

      setTimeout(() => {
        currentMessageIndex = (currentMessageIndex + 1) % messages.length;
        imageElement.src = images[currentMessageIndex];

        imageElement.style.transition = "opacity 0.5s ease-in-out";
        imageElement.style.opacity = 1;

        setTimeout(() => {
          messageInput.value = "";
          typeMessage(messages[currentMessageIndex]);
        }, 500);
      }, 500);
    }
  }, 30);
}

imageElement.src = images[currentMessageIndex];

typeMessage(messages[currentMessageIndex]);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  background-color: #000000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image-container {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  padding-right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
}

#image {
  width: 65%; 
  max-width: 432px;
  height: auto;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.message-container {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding-left: 50px;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
}

#message {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  max-width: calc(100% - 50px);
}

#message>input {
  outline: none;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: white;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  pointer
}

#image {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="message-container">
    <p id="message"><input type=text onkeydown="return false;"></input></p>
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img id="image" src="https://picsum.photos/id/50/500" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```